# Web Deploy XML File Parameterization with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, web-deployment

I was trying to use parameters.xml for web deployment of c# web project. it works fine if all parameters are pre-defined. however, in my situation, there is a group of same type items need to be configured and number of items in the group varies across different sites.

e.g. I have a group of items in **web.config** as below:

```
  <ItemConfiguration>
    <items>
      <item name="item1" label="1"  />
      <item name="item2" label="2"  />
      <item name="item3" label="3"  />       
    </items>
  </ItemConfiguration>
```

My **Parameters.xml** looks like:

```
  <parameter name="item1" defaultValue="&lt;item name='name' label='label' /&gt;">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp\\web\.config$"
      match="/configuration/itemConfiguration/items" />
  </parameter>

  <parameter name="item2" defaultValue="&lt;item name='name' label='label' /&gt;">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp\\web\.config$"
      match="/configuration/itemConfiguration/items" />
  </parameter>

  <parameter name="item3" defaultValue="&lt;item name='name' label='label' /&gt;">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp\\web\.config$"
      match="/configuration/itemConfiguration/items" />
  </parameter>
```

and my **SetParameters.xml** for one of the deployment site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  ...
  <setParameter name="item1" value="&lt;item name='book1' label='book 1'  /&gt;" />
  <setParameter name="item2" value="&lt;item name='book2' label='book 2'  /&gt;  " />
  <setParameter name="item3" value="&lt;  /&gt;" />
</parameters>
```

Above configuration allow me to set 2 items for deployment. 
My question is that if I need to configure more than the items defined in parameters.xml, say I want to have book1, book2, book3, and book4, then how can I do it? and another site might need 10 items configured in the group.

And as at the time of deploying the Parameters.xml cannot be changed anymore, only SetParameters.xml allow change, so I want to know whether I'm doing it the wrong way or there is a limitation for that.

thanks

Comment: so nobody using web deploy or some one do use it but never encountered this issue?

Comment: I have never used webdeploy so ill make this a comment. My approach in your situation would be to have a unique SetParameters file for each deployment site/server. But rather than set the value of each <item> element, set the value of the parent <items> element.

Have a read of section 2 from https://blogs.iis.net/elliotth/web-deploy-xml-file-parameterization, see if it works.

Comment: thank you, I knew that link and did learn a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you would expect as it is not dealing directly with the parameters but I would tackle the issue with another approach, simpler and more flexible IMHO:

### web.config

```
<ItemConfiguration>
    <items>
        <!-- this section to be defined by the environment config -->
    </items>
</ItemConfiguration>
```

### web.test.config

```
<ItemConfiguration>
    <items>
        <item name="item1" label="1"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
        <item name="item2" label="2"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>     
    </items>
</ItemConfiguration>
```

### web.integration.config

```
<ItemConfiguration>
    <items>
        <item name="item1" label="1"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
        <item name="item4" label="4"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
        <item name="item5" label="5"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>   
        <item name="item6" label="6"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>        
    </items>
</ItemConfiguration>
```

### web.production.config

```
<ItemConfiguration>
    <items>
        <item name="item1" label="1"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
        <item name="item2" label="2"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
        <item name="item3" label="3"  xdt:Transform="Insert"/>       
    </items>
</ItemConfiguration>
```

Also do not forget to include the definition to the config files:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
...
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you. what I want to achieve is to automatically update web.config through parameter.xml